# Memory error when multiplying two columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter

I have a data-set which looks like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        Rating       |     Installs     |     Price        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2.1        |      10,000+     |      $8.75       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          4.2        |       2,000+     |      $5.99       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3.0        |     50,0000+     |      $3.22       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I want to compute total profit (profit= Installs x Price) of all apps which have a
Rating of 3.1 or below.
I am processing strings of Price and Installs to get integer values using following code(python-jupyter):

```
Installs = data.loc[ data['Rating']>=3.1 ]["Installs"]
Price = data.loc[ data['Rating']>=3.1 ]["Price"]
Profit = Installs.apply( lambda row: int( sub(r'[^\d.]', '',row )) ) * Price.apply( lambda row: row.strip('$') )
```

But I get memory error with this command. How can I make this code more efficient such that it computes total profit without giving any memory error.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. You should split up your code a bit, transform the values into floats first. `data.loc[ data['Rating']>=3.1 ]["Installs"]` That defeats the point of using `loc`. Please share a [mcve].

Comment: @ACM This resolved my issue. Thanks.

Comment: What did? You should consider posting an answer, then, with the refactored code.